# Using Flask-OAuthlib, how do I force Facebook to ask for account on reauthentication?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, flask-oauthlib

I'm implementing authentication with OAuth 2 providers by Google and Facebook using [Flask-OAuthlib](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib) package.

For Google, I'm using this:

```
google = oauth.remote_app(
    "google",
    consumer_key=client_id,
    consumer_secret=client_secret,
    request_token_params={"scope": "email"},
    base_url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/",
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method="POST",
    access_token_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    authorize_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
)
```

For Facebook, the code is similar:

```
facebook = oauth.remote_app(
    "facebook",
    consumer_key=client_id,
    consumer_secret=client_secret,
    request_token_params={"scope": "email"},
    base_url="https://graph.facebook.com/",
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method="GET",
    access_token_url="/oauth/access_token",
    authorize_url="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth",
)
```

More complete examples are available [here](http://source.pelicandd.com/codebase/flaskblocks/).

When using Google provider, I can successfully login, and once I logoff, when I try to login again, I'm redirected to Google's page which shows the list of accounts and let me chose one.

When using Facebook provider, I can successfully login, but once I logoff, when I login again, Facebook doesn't ask anything any longer, and simply logins me automatically with the previously used account.

How do I force Facebook to reauthenticate, i.e. show every time to the user the Facebook page which makes it possible to select a given account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

The line:

```
request_token_params={"scope": "email"},
```

should be replaced by:

```
request_token_params={"scope": "email", "auth_type": "reauthenticate"},
```

In fact, according to the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication):

> To re-authenticate, you can use these same steps with additional parameters to force it:
>
> [...]
>
> `reauthenticate` - asks the person to re-authenticate unconditionally